# Nginx Rewrite with a question mark

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, wordpress, querystring

I am trying to force Nginx to redirect/rewrite one URL that uses a query string /?cat=20 to /category/lighttpd/. Here is what I tried, which is not working:

```
location ~ /\?cat=20 {
    rewrite ^ http://kevinworthington.com/category/lighttpd/? permanent;
}
```

I first tried the first line as:

```
location ~ /?cat=20 {
```

but that didn't work for me either.

This is using WordPress as the CMS, if that makes any difference.

Your help or tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just an example ...

```
location / {
    if ($arg_cat = "20") {
        return 301 http://kevinworthington.com/category/lighttpd/?;
    }
    # blablabla
}
```